# Crossfade or buffer a track using Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

I would like to buffer 5 seconds of the next track so that I can crossfade tracks.

- Is it possible using the Spotify iOS SDK? (A similar question has been asked for the older Cocoa Lib Spotify)
- Do I need to make an audio buffer to do this?
- Would somebody be able to point me in the right direction or suggest a class within the SDK reference I should try? (maybe SPTDiskCache?)